# How to change the order of "Personal Data" in ModernCV Template?

Tags: moderncv

I am currently using the `moderncv` template to write a cover letter. As part of the template, there is a section commented `%personal data`. This generates a header in the upper right hand corner of the letter, which lists out my personal data (as might be expected).

By default, the information is listed in following order:

- Full Name
- Address
- Cellphone Number
- Email address
- Personal website.

I want to change this to be in the following order:

- Full Name
- **Personal website**
- Address
- Cellphone Number
- Email address.

I have tried placing the text in my LaTeX document to follow the order I would like, however that did not have any effect. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The order is hardcoded, as the template/style defines the layout and order of stuff. If you want to change it, most simple way is to change the styles (for example `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`) directly according to the license of te files.

Comment: @Johannes_B  Thank you very much for your answer. How would I go about doing what you suggested? Could you point me to some resource which would give me information about doing so?

Answer (score 2):

With style `banking` class `moderncv` uses `moderncvheadiii` to build the shown header for cv **and** letter.  To change there the order you have to change the hard coded order from the class. To do that I copied the code from the class and changed it.

Please see the following MWE (check the added code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and see the main changing marked with `<========`)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % \rmdefault
%\nopagenumbers{} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
%\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{Jun-Sep, 2011} 
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % for the 'classic' style

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

%\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}

\makeatletter % <===========================================================
\@initializecommand{\makehead}{%
  \setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\makeheaddetailswidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % optional detailed information
    \if@details{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}% <========================== moved
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
        \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
%     \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}% <=============================================== original place
      \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmakeheaddetails}\fi}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makehead
\makeatother % <============================================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

%\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file


\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting header in pdf]

Please see that if you change the style from `banking` to `classic` or ...  another file `moderncvhead???` is called and therefore you have to change that code ...